# IP2, IP4 relationship with P1 dB of an amplifier

Tags: electrical-engineering, rf-electronics

It is well known that the difference between IP3 and P1 dB of an amplifier can be derived and results in a theoretical 9.6 dB difference. Can a similar relationship be derived for IP2 and IP4?

Comment: What is IP2, IP3 and IP4? Sorry I cannot read your mind. If the subject is well know can you please provide some references and your understanding

Comment: These are metrics used to define the linearity of  an amplifier

Comment: Can you explain these matrix or provide some reference in the body of question? Does IP -> Intercept point?

Comment: Yes IP is intercept point, so you have the second order intercept point IP2, you have the third order intercept point IP3, the fourth order intercept point  IP4, etc..

Comment: You question is niche, in order to attract good responses, I suggest adding more details such as your research, and any of your attempts to solve the problem.